# How to handle user refresh of page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, page-refresh

this sounds quite basic...
I have views that are built in controllers with some input argument (from previous page) and more stuff like getting data from TempData[] and more.

```
 public ActionResult Submit(SubmitDetails submitDetails)
{
    var x = (long)TempData["SomeMoreValue"];
    // do stuff 
   return View("NextView", someInputModelThatIHaveBuilt);
}
```

Everything is working, but when I hit refresh on Next view, got Resource not found...
My Question - what is the practice to keep it up with the info you need in "NextView" to survive user refresh...

Comment: Maybe passing "SomeMoreValue" as get parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using:

```
TempData.Keep();
```

Comment: and what about SubmitDetails instance? should I reside as well in TempData? this is the practice in every control? immedietly save all inputs in TempData and do keep?

Comment: To store values between requests you can use:
- cookies
- session
- query strings
- store it in the db..
TempData is good for storing data like error inf "Save failed" etc. and it is cleared out at the end of the next request.  
If you don't want to loose inf from temptada call TempData.Keep().